# tlmgr viaTeX Live Backports PPA

Tags: ppa, latex

I just installed TeX Live 2012, --on `ubuntu 12.04`-- via a [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa), but cannot seem to figure out how to install `tlmgr`. I need help installing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56005/tlmgr-with-ubuntu-texlive) - the TeXLive installed via PPA most likely (I don't use Ubuntu) does not contain tlmgr. If you need tlmgr, install TL2012 directly.

Comment: Thank you. I vividly remember going through that post, but figured the texlive 2012 backport was an exception. I just figured that perhaps there was something I could have overlooked, especially that I installed `texlive-full`

Comment: @phiri: I doubt that any distribution includes tlmgr, as thou shall only install packages through the distribution's package manager, not tlmgr.

Comment: thank you for this. Incidentally, I managed to manually [1] install what I wanted.

[1]http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39165/17923

Comment: @phiri: That's IMHO useless: Install pristine TL2012 instead, either from CTAN or from [Debian](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html).